# Records with a field that is a sum

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I am trying to create a multiple items form in MS Access where each record has a field that is an aggregate value. That is, I have two tables with a one to many relationship. For each record in table a (the 'one' in the one to many), I would like to sum a field from table b (the 'many' in the one to many).

I tried using a record source with an INNER JOIN and SUM sql statements but this does not work because the SUM function only returns a single aggregate value (only one row with a sum of all the records). I want one row for each unique record in table a and having a field that sums all the related records from table b.

Oh gosh. I hope this makes sense to those who read it. My explanation seems like it can be confusing but I am not sure how to clarify it more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound simple:

```
select 
    a.Field1, sum(b.Field2) as sumOfField2
from
    [yourTableA] as a
    inner join [yourTableB] as b on a.id = b.idOfA
group by 
    a.Field1
```

This should give one aggregate value for every value of `Field1`. Replace the field and table names to suit your needs.

Tips:

1. If you need to group by more values, add them to your field list (the `select` part of the instruction) **and** to your grouping fields (the `group by` part of the instruction)
2. If you need to show also the values of table a that don't have any related record in table b, replace `inner join` with `left join` (the sum will be zero)

Hope this helps

Comment: Simple when you know what you're doing. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. It definitely helps ... and is simple now that I know what to do.

Comment: @Jslick Tips for future reference: Keep at hand a good SQL reference. You'll need to understand how to relate tables to squeeze the most of them. I'm happy to help